# Hadoop 2.7.3 Java Runtime error - core-site.xml not found

Tags: java, hadoop2.7.3

When running the `hdfs dfs -mkdir /abc` I get the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: core-site.xml not found
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResource(Configuration.java:2577)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.loadResources(Configuration.java:2503)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getProps(Configuration.java:2409)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1144)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.set(Configuration.java:1116)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.setBoolean(Configuration.java:1454)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.processGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:319)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:485)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:170)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.<init>(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:64)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:84)
at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FsShell.main(FsShell.java:372)
```

the path to my core-site.xml is /usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml.

How to fix this error?

Comment: do you have proper permission to access the same file.

Comment: Yes.  It is -rw-rw-r--

Comment: What is the value set for `$HADOOP_CONF_DIR`?

Comment: Thanks. Hadn't set it up.

Answer (score 6):

Can you try to set the below variable in ~/.bash_profile or at the start of the script.

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=**location of your hadoop in local**
```

like (`/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.7.3/etc/hadoop` )

You can also look into the below link :

https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Storage-Random-Access-HDFS/RuntimeException-running-the-hdfs-command-core-site-xml-not/td-p/28224

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm